# iOS: Bluetooth listner

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to listen data pushed from Bluetooth Pedometer and insulin pump into my iPhone app via Bluetooth connectivity. Is it possible to listen for receiving data from an another bluetooth devices into our iPhone app? If possible, please advise how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: That depends.  You can use Core Bluetooth to interact with Bluetooth LTE devices, but that is about it.

Comment: Hi, Are you saying it is possible to listen for Bluetooth data to receive from other BT enabled devices to an iOS app or not ?

Comment: Only certain types (i.e. LTE devices).  Check the Core Bluetooth programming guide.